# Default brower for different programs

Tags: browser, hyperlink, default-settings

Is there a way to have two (or more) default browsers, depending on the source program?

For example:
I want all the links from outlook to open in Chrome but all the links from PowerPoint to open in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no.  Applications dont know what browsers are installed, or even if there are any at all.  The program simply makes a request to the operating system to open a browser and go to the provided URL.  The operating system will open the browser that is set as default.